# XMLSerialization: The type of the argument object 'Sw' is not primitive

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, primitive, derived-class

I'm trying to serialize an object to an XML file, but am getting the above error.

The problem seems to be with objects that contain a list of a base class but is populated by objects derived from the base class.

Example code is as follows:

```
public class myObject
{
    public myObject()
    {
        this.list.Add(new Sw());
    }

    public List<Units> list = new List<Units>();
}

public class Units
{
    public Units()
    {
    }
}

public class Sw : Units
{
    public Sw();
    {
    }

    public void main()
    {
        myObject myObject = new myObject();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myObject));
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter ("file.xml");
        serializer.Serialize (textWriter, myObject);
    }
```

E.g. an object that contains only a `List<Units>` which is populated by derived objects which inherit from the `Units` class (`Sw`).

Sorry for not providing my actual code but the objects involved are quite complex and this seems to be the only part of the object which wont successfully be serialized - and only when the list contains the derived classes.

How can I correctly serialize a class like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mark `Units` class with `XmlInclude` attribute passing your derived class as parameter:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Sw))]
public class Units
{
    public Units()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Was very hard to find a simple answer to what I assumed was a simple problem. My code now works, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To Serialize an object to XML. you can use the following code

```
public String SerializeResponse(SW sw)
{
    try
    {
        String XmlizedString = null;
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SW));
        //create an instance of the MemoryStream class since we intend to keep the XML string 
        //in memory instead of saving it to a file.
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        //XmlTextWriter - fast, non-cached, forward-only way of generating streams or files 
        //containing XML data
        XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        //Serialize emp in the xmlTextWriter
        xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, sw);
        //Get the BaseStream of the xmlTextWriter in the Memory Stream
        memoryStream = (MemoryStream)xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
        //Convert to array
        XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        return XmlizedString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

The method will return an XML String and to make the above function you need to import the following libraries:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer provided, however it wasn't really what I was asking. Apologies for any confusion.