# InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object 'Scratch' is not primitive

Tags: c#, xml, list, unity-game-engine, xml-serialization

So there's the error.

> InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object 'Scratch' is not primitive

What I'm doing is serializing a list of classes (`List<BaseEnemy>`). The BaseEnemy class also has a list in it of classes (`List<BaseMoves>`). When I run things, the list of BaseEnemy serializes properly. However, the list of BaseMoves does not. `Scratch` is a class that derives from BaseMove that is stored in the `List<BaseMove>`.

That ***WAS*** the problem that I was having. I found the answer on here...[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917831/xmlserialization-the-type-of-the-argument-object-sw-is-not-primitive)...

> "Mark BaseMove class with XmlInclude attribute passing your derived class
>   as parameter:"

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Scratch))]
public class BaseMove
{
    public BaseMove()
    {
    }
}
```

Works like a charm! So why am I posting this here? New question. I have **HUNDREDS** of moves that derive from BaseMove. Is there a shortcut or do I have to write every single "typeof(...)" in the XmlInclude?

**EDIT - Another solution I found.**

```
public static Type[] GetAllSubTypes(Type aBaseClass)
{
    List<Type> result = new List<Type>();
    Assembly[] assemblies = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    foreach (Assembly a in assemblies)
    {
        Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
        foreach (Type t in types)
        {
            if (t.IsSubclassOf(aBaseClass))
                result.Add(t);
        }
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

**And then during the serialization I just call this function to use as an Array of extraTypes.**

```
Type[] extraTypes = GetAllSubTypes(typeof(BaseMove));
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BaseEnemy>), extraTypes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through all the assemblies in your app domain, find all types assignable from your base type, and pass them as known types when constructing your `XmlSerializer`.  However, some caveats:

1. Assemblies are loaded on demand so you cannot perform the search just once, and
2. The `XmlSerializer`, once constructed, must be cached in a hash table or dictionary and reused to prevent memory and resource leaks.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for details.

Thus, you could do something like:

```
public static class XmlSerializerWithKnownTypeCreator<T>
{
    static Dictionary<HashSet<Type>, XmlSerializer> table = new Dictionary<HashSet<Type>, XmlSerializer>(HashSet<Type>.CreateSetComparer());

    public static XmlSerializer CreateKnownTypeSerializer<TRoot>()
    {
        return CreateKnownTypeSerializer(new Type [] {typeof(TRoot)});
    }

    public static XmlSerializer CreateKnownTypeSerializer(IEnumerable<Type> baseTypes)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<Type>(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => baseTypes.Any(baseType => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t))));
        lock (table)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer;
            if (table.TryGetValue(set, out serializer))
                return serializer;

            table[set] = serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), set.ToArray());
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
var serializer = XmlSerializerWithKnownTypeCreator<DocumentRoot>.CreateKnownTypeSerializer<BaseMove>();
```

For instance,

```
var serializer = XmlSerializerWithKnownTypeCreator<List<BaseClass>>.CreateKnownTypeSerializer<BaseMove>();
```

**Update**

If the parameterized generic static table of serializers looks weird (and to be fair, it kind of does), you can store the serializers in a non-generic global hash table, as is suggested in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable, as shown in the following example.

However, the doc sort of glosses over how to generate a key for the `XmlSerializer`.  The code sample also isn't thread-safe, perhaps since all this stuff dates back to .Net 1.0.  So here's some logic that will correctly key and recycle an `XmlSerializer` with known extra types, in a global hash table:

```
public abstract class XmlserializerKey
{
    readonly Type serializerType;

    public XmlserializerKey(Type serializerType)
    {
        this.serializerType = serializerType;
    }

    protected Type SerializerType { get { return serializerType; } }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        else if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (GetType() != obj.GetType())
            return false;
        XmlserializerKey other = (XmlserializerKey)obj;
        if (other.serializerType != serializerType)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int code = 0;
        if (serializerType != null)
            code ^= serializerType.GetHashCode();
        return code;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Serializer type: " + serializerType.ToString());
    }
}

public abstract class XmlserializerKeyWithExtraTypes : XmlserializerKey
{
    static IEqualityComparer<HashSet<Type>> comparer;

    readonly HashSet<Type> moreTypes = new HashSet<Type>();

    static XmlserializerKeyWithExtraTypes()
    {
        comparer = HashSet<Type>.CreateSetComparer();
    }

    public XmlserializerKeyWithExtraTypes(Type serializerType, IEnumerable<Type> extraTypes)
        : base(serializerType)
    {
        if (extraTypes != null)
            foreach (var type in extraTypes)
                moreTypes.Add(type);
    }

    protected Type[] MoreTypes { get { return moreTypes.ToArray(); } }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!base.Equals(obj))
            return false;
        XmlserializerKeyWithExtraTypes other = (XmlserializerKeyWithExtraTypes)obj;
        return comparer.Equals(moreTypes, other.moreTypes);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int code = base.GetHashCode();
        if (moreTypes != null)
            code ^= comparer.GetHashCode(moreTypes);
        return code;
    }
}

public sealed class XmlSerializerKeyWithKnownTypes : XmlserializerKeyWithExtraTypes
{
    public XmlSerializerKeyWithKnownTypes(Type serializerType, IEnumerable<Type> otherTypes)
        : base(serializerType, otherTypes)
    {
    }

    public XmlSerializer CreateSerializer()
    {
        return new XmlSerializer(SerializerType, MoreTypes);
    }
}

public static class XmlSerializerHashTable
{
    static Dictionary<object, XmlSerializer> dict;

    static XmlSerializerHashTable()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<object, XmlSerializer>();
    }

    public static XmlSerializer DemandSerializer(object key, Func<object, XmlSerializer> factory)
    {
        lock (dict)
        {
            XmlSerializer value;
            if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                dict[key] = value = factory(key);
            return value;
        }
    }
}

public static class XmlSerializerWithKnownDerivedTypesCreator
{
    public static XmlSerializer CreateKnownTypeSerializer(Type type, IEnumerable<Type> extraTypes)
    {
        var allExtraTypes = 
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .Where(t => extraTypes.Any(extraType => extraType.IsAssignableFrom(t)));
        var key = new XmlSerializerKeyWithKnownTypes(type, allExtraTypes);
        return XmlSerializerHashTable.DemandSerializer(key, k => ((XmlSerializerKeyWithKnownTypes)k).CreateSerializer());
    }
}
```

And then call it in the same way as you would call the equivalent [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5aakyae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor:

```
    public static void Test2()
    {
        List<BaseClass> list = new List<BaseClass>();
        list.Add(new BaseClass());
        list.Add(new MidClass());
        list.Add(new DerivedClass1());
        list.Add(new DerivedClass2());

        var serializer = XmlSerializerWithKnownDerivedTypesCreator.CreateKnownTypeSerializer(list.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(BaseClass) });
        string xml = XmlSerializationHelper.GetXml(list, serializer, false);
        Debug.WriteLine(xml);

        // No assert below:
        Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(serializer, XmlSerializerWithKnownDerivedTypesCreator.CreateKnownTypeSerializer(list.GetType(), new Type[] { typeof(BaseClass) })));
    }
```

Comment: Hey @dbc I know it's been a few days but I've recently got some free time and I'm trying to see if I'm going about your suggestion correctly. In the original question I edited to add what I've written out so far. Am I on the right track? (Oh...and would I put all of this in my class that handles saving & loading?)

Comment: @DavidRosenIII - You wouldn't do `public static class XmlSerializerWithKnownTypeCreator<List<BaseMove>>`.  This is a generic static class, where the generic parameter corresponds to the type passed to `XmlSerializer`.  (I thought this would be more convenient than some global hash table.)  Leave it as `XmlSerializerWithKnownTypeCreator<T>` then use it like `var serializer = XmlSerializerWithKnownTypeCreator<List<BaseMove>>.CreateKnownTypeSerializer<BaseMove>();`

Comment: Thanks. x_x Don't know what I was thinking, but it HAS been a long week. I also came across a neat little static function in another question here on stackoverflow. I've posted it up in the original post. I implemented it and it's working great, but somehow I get the feeling you're going to say I still need to do the hash table or dictionary steps.

Comment: @DavidRosenIII - Sadly, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly say "If you use any of the other constructors, multiple versions of the same assembly are generated and never unloaded, which results in a memory leak and poor performance. The easiest solution is to use one of the previously mentioned two constructors. Otherwise, you must cache the assemblies in a Hashtable".  If the generic static version looks weird, I there's a non-generic version I can suggest.