# Serializing class that contain an instance of a class from list of classes that implement an interface c#

Tags: c#, serialization, interface

I have a class `MyClass` that need to be serialized, one property will get a list of classes that implement `ICamera` and create one instance of the class selected in the propertygrid

Is it possible for me to serialize the class with the selected instance. I want it to be done dynamically without the `MyClass` has any idea about the classes implements `ICamera`

Here is an example of my code so far

```
[XmlRoot("MyClass")]
public class MyClass 
{
     private List<string> GetClassesImplementICameraList()
     {
        List<string> classObject = new List<string>();
        var classesWithProperties =
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICamera)) && t.IsClass)
        .Select(c => new { ClassName = c.FullName})
        .ToList();

        foreach (var field in classesWithProperties)
        {     
            classObject.Add(field.ClassName);
        }

        return classObject;
     }

     [Browsable(false)]
     public List<string> CameraClassesList
     {
         get { return GetClassesImplementICameraList(); }
     }

     private ICamera _Camera = null;
     [Category("Camera")]
     [Description("The camera physically connected to the frame grabber.")]
     public ICamera Camera
     {
         get { return _Camera as ICamera; }
     }

     private string _CameraMode = string.Empty;
     [TypeConverter(typeof(CameraModeTypeConverter))]
     [XmlIgnore]
     [Category("Camera")]
     public string CameraMode 
     { 
         get
         {
             return _CameraMode;
         } 
         set
         { 
             _CameraMode = value;
             _Camera = GetCameraInstance(_CameraMode);
         } 
     }

     private ICamera GetCameraInstance(string name)
     {
         ICamera cameraInstance = null;
         var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                       where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICamera))
                                && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null && t.FullName == name
                       select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as ICamera;

         foreach (var instance in instances)
         {
            cameraInstance = instance;
         }
         return cameraInstance;
     }
}
```

Comment: check out [the documentation for the XMLSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.  note, you can use `myObj.GetType()` to get the type from an instance of an object

Comment: if i get type of the object how i can serialize it?

Comment: look at the documentation.  I only included the bit about `GetType()` because it can be used in place of `typeof()`

Comment: You can do something along the lines of [InvalidOperationException: The type of the argument object 'Scratch' is not primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391485/invalidoperationexception-the-type-of-the-argument-object-scratch-is-not-prim/27392367#27392367) or [Serializing an array of multiple types using XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462449) but honestly, it's a nuisance.